# Why does this if statement, with an assignment and equality check, evaluate to false?

Tags: java, if-statement, logic

How does a Java *if statement* work when it has an assignment and an equality check `OR`-d together??

```
public static void test() {
    boolean test1 = true; 
    if (test1 = false || test1 == false) {
        System.out.println("TRUE");
    } else {
        System.out.println("FALSE");
    }       
}
```

Why is this printing FALSE?

Comment: Run and check. See what boolean value is printed if you assign false and if you assign true. Then read on how OR works.

Comment: I would like to tell that this code on debug mode gives TRUE value and on Running mode gives FALSE value... Why it is so ???... (I put my breakpoint on if condition)...

Comment: `test1=false`, `test1==false` is `false`, `false || false` is `false or false` which is `false`.

Comment: I know you weren't asking for advice, but as the answers below identify a precedence issue, here are a couple of practices that have helped me avoid trouble (when I stick to these):  (1) always use parentheses when not 100% certain of precedence or for easier legibility to help other developers.  Don't assume others will remember precedence rules for all operators (2) if-assignments should generally be avoided to reduce confusion except for very simple if-conditions.  There are some common exceptions (especially with simple checks for I/O, networking, etc).  Just my two cents.

Comment: because `test1 = true`

Comment: Of course the most pertinent point is that this would fail code review and the author would be sent away and told to come back with something more sensible.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

The expression is not parsed the way you think. It's not

```
(test1=false) || (test1 == false)
```

in which case the result would have been `true`, but

```
test1 = (false || test1 == false)
```

The value of `false || test1 == false` expression is computed first, and it is `false`, because `test1` is set to `true` going into the computation.

The reason it is parsed this way is that the [precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) of the `||` is lower than that of the `==` operator, but higher than the precedence of the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: +1 @RohanFernando, please also note that if you would add brackets around the assignment like so: `((test1 = false) || test1 == false)` the overall value would be `true`.

Comment: Please write the reason why parsing happens so...Is it because of the priority order of operators?

Comment: @kondu That's a fair follow-up question, I edited to add a link to a precedence table, which shows that `==` is above `||`, but `=` is below `||`.

Comment: The final paragraph is misleading, in the sense that to understand why the second parsing is chosen rather than the first, it suffices to know the (easily remembered) rule that assignment has lower precedence any non-assignment operator (here `||`). The relative precedence of `||` and `==` is only relevant to show that parsing is **not** as in `test1 = ((false || test1) == false)`, which I don't think anybody would reasonably expect (by the way that relative precedence, or more generally that  `||`,  `&&` have lower precedence than relations, is also easy to remember, since used all the time).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The relative precedence of `||` and `==` vs `||` and `=` explains why this behaves differently from the (common) case of `a == b || c == d`.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I am, for the record, not the author of this answer.

Comment: People keep saying that `false || test1 == false` evaluates to `false` because `test1` is set to `true` prior. But `||` operator short circuiting is at play here isn't it? It evaluates to `false` purely because the left operand is hard coded to `false`. The right hand operand `test1 == false` is never evaluated.

Comment: @AdamSmith Short circuiting is applicable to `||` only when the first part evaluates to `true`. It is `&&` that short-circuits on `false`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Man I always get my `||`'s and `&&`'s mixed up! Thanks mate.

Answer (score 83):

This is a precedence issue, basically. You're assuming that your code is equivalent to:

```
if ((test1 = false) || (test1 == false))
```

... but it's not. It's actually equivalent to:

```
if (test1 = (false || test1 == false))
```

... which is equivalent to:

```
if (test1 = (false || false))
```

(because `test1` is `true` to start with)

... which is equivalent to:

```
if (test1 = false)
```

which assigns the value `false` to `test1`, with the result of the expression being `false`.

See the [Java tutorial on operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for a useful table of operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

[image: please have a look over precedence of operators]

Expression `test1 = false || test1 == false` will evaluate in following step.

**STEP:1-** `test1 = false || test1 == false` //precedence of `==` is highest

**STEP:2-** `test1 = false || false`// Operator `||` have higher precedence

**STEP:3-** `test1 = false`

**STEP:4-** `false`

Since boolean value of expression becomes false.So else statement is being executed.

Answer (score -11):

`(test1 = false || test1 == false)` returns false, because both of them are false.`(test1 = false || test1 == true)` this is true because one of them is true

Comment: Completely wrong. Why would you answer with such incorrect information days after the question has received two high quality answers which describe what happens?

Comment: Two answers of such low quality do not deserve individually written comments. You do realize your answer is nonsense, right? If not, carefully read the two answers by Jon and blinkenlight.